# Paper Trail: create a version on parent whenever associated model changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I'm working on a Rails app where I need to show the audit trail on a **Record**, which has_many **Data**. I have paper_trail on my Record, and associated Datum models, and it is saving versions of them just fine.

However, what I need is for **one** version for Record to be created whenever **one or more** associated Data are changed. Currently, it creates versions on each Datum that changes, but it only creates a version of the Record if the Record's attributes change; it's not doing it when the associated Data change.

I tried putting touch_with_version in Record's after_touch callback, like so:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :data

  has_paper_trail

  after_touch do |record|
    puts 'touched record'
    record.touch_with_version
  end

end
```

and

```
class Datum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :record, :touch => true

  has_paper_trail

end
```

The after_touch callback fires, but unfortunately it creates a new version for each Datum, so when a Record is created it already has like 10 versions, one for each Datum.

Is there a way to tell in the callbacks if a version has been created, so I don't create multiples? Like check in one of the Record callbacks and if Datum has already triggered a version, don't do any more?

Thanks!

Comment: I think `after_touch` is a good idea, but might be tricky to prevent duplicate versions of `Record`. Instead, what about starting a transaction, updating your `Data`, updating your `Record`, then committing the transaction.  If all the updates happen in the same transaction, what result do you get?

Comment: A transaction sounds like what I want, but I didn't have to create one, I think I just got it for free because all the `Data` `belong_to` the `Record`, so all those saves just happen in the course of create/update for `Record`. One other wrinkle--if multiple `Data` would create multiple versions on `Record`, I think I need to keep the _last_ version, not the first, if I want Record to be synced with its Data. Thanks for your advice--I'm still new to Rails and I'm not sure if I'm quite thinking in Rails yet. Working on it!

Comment: @JaredBeck, how might I set up that transaction? `Record`'s data attributes are already in a transaction(I think?) because of the Rails association. Should I turn off the paper_trail callbacks, like: `has_paper_trail on: []`, and then create my own `after_create` and `after_update` callbacks with 
```
    Record.transaction do
      record.update
      record.touch_with_version
    end
```

Comment: For documentation on transactions in ActiveRecord, you might start here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pessimistic-locking

Comment: If you're new to rails, I wouldn't recommend using PaperTrail's assocations feature yet, as it is experimental and has a few known issues.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the Guides page, I had searched there for transactions but didn't see that. And I saw the caveats on associations, but I don't think any of them apply to me; my Data are only ever accessed through Record. I ended up coming at the problem from another direction; paper_trail is saving Record and Data (I'm not losing data anywhere), so I'm coming at the problem from the view end. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DavidHam So you gave up to create one Record.version when associated model changes?

Comment: I did, but there is another approach I found afterward that I haven't tried yet. (In my case, there was always a change to the parent's status property whenever a child Datum changed, so it was sort of moot.) But I think if I did `belongs_to :record, touch: true` in my Datum class, it would create the timestamp I want on my Record.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  before_update :check_update

  def check_update
    return if changed_notably?

    tracking_has_many_associations = [ ... ]
    tracking_has_has_one_associations = [ ... ]

    tracking_has_many_associations.each do |a|
      send(a).each do |r|
        if r.send(:changed_notably?) || r.marked_for_destruction?
          self.touch
          return
        end
      end
    end
    tracking_has_one_associations.each do |a|
      r = send(a)
      if r.send(:changed_notably?) || r.marked_for_destruction?
        self.touch
        return
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You may have to prefix the call to :changed_notably? with with a call to paper_trail first.  e.g. instead of `changed_notably? => `paper_trail.changed_notably?`