# Any way to detect if one or more association changes in rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to call some methods only once when one or more association changes.

Comment: What do you mean by change in association?

Comment: I agree - give an example please.

Comment: @Guido create, update or destroy.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to achieve this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043447/paper-trail-create-a-version-on-parent-whenever-associated-model-changes

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for are callbacks:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

For example:

```
after_destroy :do_something

private

def do_something
   ...
end
```

Comment: When more than one associations changed, the callback is called more than once.

Comment: Could you give us an example?

Comment: I'm trying to solve this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043447/paper-trail-create-a-version-on-parent-whenever-associated-model-changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`set_callback`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html) callback i.e

```
class Xyz < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_callback :save, :after,  :after_method, if: :condition

  def after_method

  end
end
```

Comment: Will this trigger when only association record data changed?

Comment: It will only triggers if there is a change in the record...nothing is going to happen if the record remains unchanged.

Comment: When I try after_update, the callback method is triggered even when no data changes.

Comment: Yes, I've already found the way, but my model has many associations, so I don't want to override all of the setter methods.

Comment: I tried `after_save` but the callback method is trigger even when no data changes. Please stop spamming me...

Comment: I was reading through and I realise you can use `set_callback`. I have edit the answer.

Comment: Uhm? I think those callbacks do not care the association changes, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind not knowing exactly which associated record changed, it would be a good job for touch:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category, touch: true
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  after_touch :update_name_cache

  private

  def update_name_cache
    PostNameCache.new( self ).set posts.pluck :name
  end
end
```

Comment: When multiple association changes, the callback method is called multiple times, right? That's not what I want.

Comment: If you set `touch` on multiple associations, yes.

Comment: That's not what I want. Please read my question. Thanks for your answer though.