# What is the most efficient method to list all PaperTrail versions including associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

This question pertains to the gem [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) for Rails.

When only associations change, a version record will not be created for the main model. Therefore, what is the most efficient method to list all versions for a certain record including its associations?

Should the query be something like the following?

```rb
f = "(item_type = 'Place' AND item_id = ?) OR (item_type = 'PlaceName' AND item_id IN (?))"
PaperTrail::Version.where(f, @place.id, @place.names.map { |n| n.id })
```

The SQL query above might be too long and slow performance.

Or should a version record be created when only associations are changed?

I think David Ham tried a similar approach based on [his related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043447/paper-trail-create-a-version-on-parent-whenever-associated-model-changes).

Comment: To track associations with this approach, associations must be soft deleted when we need to delete them.

Answer (score 3):

So, I sort of found a way to do this, but it's not exactly pretty and it doesn't create a new version everytime an association is changed.  It does, however, give you an efficient way to retrieve the versions chronologically so you can see what the version looked like before/after association changes.

First, I retrieve all the ids for for the asscoiation versions given the id of that model:

```
def associations_version_ids(item_id=nil)
  if !item_id.nil?
    ids = PaperTrail::VersionAssociation.where(foreign_key_id: item_id, foreign_key_name: 'item_id').select(:version_id)

    return ids
  else
    ids = PaperTrail::VersionAssociation.where(foreign_key_name: 'item_id').select(:version_id)

    return ids
  end
end
```

Then I get all versions together using the VersionAssociation ids from this function.  It will return a chronological array of PaperTrail::Version's.  So the information is useful for an activity log, etc.  And it's pretty simple to piece back together a version and its associations this way:

```
def all_versions
  if !@item_id.nil?
    association_version_ids = associations_version_ids(@item_id)
    all_versions = PaperTrail::Version
                      .where("(item_type = ? AND item_id = ?) OR id IN (?)", 'Item', @item_id, association_version_ids)
                      .where("object_changes IS NOT NULL")
                      .order(created_at: :desc)

    return all_versions
  else
    assocation_ids = associations_version_ids
    all_versions = PaperTrail::Version
                      .where("item_type = ? OR id IN (?)", 'Item', association_ids)
                      .where("object_changes IS NOT NULL")
                      .order(created_at: :desc)

    return all_versions
  end
end
```

Again, not a perfect answer since there isn't a new version everytime there's a change, but it's manageable.

Comment: Item is the main model?
When will the item_id be nil?

Comment: Yea Item is the main model.  So the case for item_id being nil should use all records for that model.  To be honest, that portion hasn't been used/tested, so I can edit my code sample without it if you'd like.

Comment: I tried your code, but it misses some association versions.

Comment: My main model is Place, but some of its associations' foreign_key_name are not 'place_id'.

Comment: Haha well, my model's name makes my example hairy.  So the item_id, wouldn't become place_id in your case, it would still be item_id.  item_type and item_id are the column names in the Versions table.

Your item_type = "Place" and you item_id = @place_id

(Just a heads up, my instance variables were set in the init of some service i built to do this.)

Comment: So I tried following code, but it misses all the association versions.

`ids = PaperTrail::VersionAssociation.where(foreign_key_id: @place.id, foreign_key_name: 'item_id').select(:version_id);
@versions = PaperTrail::Version.where("(item_type = ? AND item_id = ?) OR id IN (?)", 'Place', @place.id, ids).order('created_at DESC')`

Comment: That was what I was doing and it missed some association versions.

Comment: Try this:
 `ids = PaperTrail::VersionAssociation.where(foreign_key_id: @place.id, foreign_key_name: 'place_id').select(:version_id); @versions = PaperTrail::Version.where("(item_type = ? AND item_id = ?) OR id IN (?)", 'Place', @place.id, ids).order('created_at DESC')`

Comment: As I said it does not work. Its associations' foreign_key_name are not always 'place_id'.

Comment: It seems polymorphic associations use different foreign_key_name.

Comment: Oh, well in your code snippet you have foreign_key_name: 'item_id'

If Place is the main model, it should grab off of the Place Versions and its associated versions then order them by created_at.  Are there multiple associations on those other models?


EDIT:  Ah, yea I don't have any polymorphic joins on these models.  Add an OR in there and see how that goes.  Curious to know since I do have some polymorphic joins in our library.

Comment: I think this code might not work because we cannot know linkable_type values. `PaperTrail::VersionAssociation.where(foreign_key_id: @place.id, foreign_key_name: ['place_id', 'linkable_id']).select(:version_id)`

Comment: I tried this: `Version.includes(:associations, :item).references(:item).where("(item_type = 'Place' AND item_id = 1251) OR (item_type = 'Link' AND item.linkable_type = 'Place' AND linkable_id = 1251)")` but I get `ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError: Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :item`. (Version is extended from PaperTrail::Version to set `has_many :associations, class_name: 'PaperTrail::VersionAssociation'`) EDIT: I just realized item might be already deleted, so I think cannot use this approach.

Comment: Ah bummer, sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an approach than a specific answer, but here goes.

In my case, I needed a version history such that any time anyone changed a `Child`, they also changed a flag on the `Parent'. But I needed a way to show an audit trail that would show the initial values for all the children, and an audit line for the parent whenever anyone changed a child.

So, much simplified, it's like this:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

So, whenever there's a change on a `Child` we need to create a version on the `Parent`.

First, try changing `Child` as follows:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  belongs_to :parent, touch: true
end
```

This should (should! have not tested) create a timestamp on the `Parent` whenever the `Child` changes.

Then, to get the state of the `:children` at each version of `Parent`, you search the `Child`'s versions for the one where the `transaction_id` matches the `Parent`.

```
# loop through the parent versions
@parent.versions.each do |version|

  @parent.children.versions.each do |child|
    # Then loop through the children and get the version of the Child where the transaction_id matches the given Parent version
    child_version = child.versions.find_by transaction_id: version.transaction_id

    if child_version # it will only exist if this Child changed in this Parent's version
      # do stuff with the child's version
    end
```

This worked in my situation, hope something in here is useful for you.

Comment: When you use `touch: true` and create multiple children at the same time, how do you prevent to create multiple version for the parent?

Comment: The last code block (`@parent.versions.each ...`) is to list versions?

Comment: As to your first question, I never did figure out the issue of multiple versions of the parent, but in my case there was always a property that was set on the parent when a child changed, so I didn't have to worry about it, and I abandoned `touch: true.` Though if, say, you're changing three `:children` with `touch: true`, but not the parent, in the same throw, and you're doing versions with transactions, it might only make one version on the parent--I don't know if it would do one for each child change and give them all the same `transaction_id`.

Comment: I think you cannot paginate versions if you do that way, correct?

Comment: I dunno, I haven't had to deal with that yet.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

I found a better way to list all PaperTrail versions including associations. I updated the associations inside a transaction to make the code work.

```rb
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  before_update :check_update

  def check_update
    return if changed_notably?

    tracking_has_many_associations = [ ... ]
    tracking_has_has_one_associations = [ ... ]

    tracking_has_many_associations.each do |a|
      send(a).each do |r|
        if r.send(:changed_notably?) || r.marked_for_destruction?
          self.updated_at = DateTime.now
          return
        end
      end
    end
    tracking_has_one_associations.each do |a|
      r = send(a)
      if r.send(:changed_notably?) || r.marked_for_destruction?
        self.updated_at = DateTime.now
        return
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class Version < PaperTrail::Version
  def associated_versions
    Version.where(transaction_id: transaction_id) if transaction_id
  end
end
```

### Original answer

The following code is the most efficient method that I have found so far.

Thank you, John Schaum for your answer which helped me.

Before I started, I added a column named `polymorphic_type` to the 'versions' table.

```rb
class AddPolymorphicTypeToVersions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :versions, :polymorphic_type, :string
  end
end
```

And then I set up the models as follows.

```rb
# app/models/version.rb
class Version < PaperTrail::Version
  has_many :associations, class_name: 'PaperTrail::VersionAssociation'
end
```

```rb
# app/models/link.rb
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail meta: { polymorphic_type: :linkable_type }
  belongs_to :linkable, polymorphic: true
end
```

```rb
# app/models/place.rb
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  has_many :links, as: :linkable

  def all_versions
    f = '(item_type = "Place" AND item_id = ?) OR ' +
        '(foreign_key_name = "place_id" AND foreign_key_id = ?) OR ' +
        '(polymorphic_type = "Place" AND foreign_key_id = ?)'
    Version.includes(:associations).references(:associations).where(f, id, id, id)
  end
end
```

Now I can get its versions, including associations, using the following line of code.

```rb
@place.all_versions.order('created_at DESC')
```